# How to make Server-Sent Events efficient

Tags: javascript, php, html, server, server-sent-events

I am currently working on an application that utilizes Server-Sent Events. I truly enjoy how easy they are to setup when compared to WebSockets (which I have yet to figure out how to setup). If you are not familiard with this technology, server sent events allows for one to keep an open connection with a server for a unidirectional flow of data from the server to the client.

However, I am not exactly sure how to run these SSE's in the most efficient fashion. I have two options here:

1. Continuously let the SSE's run.
2. Open and Close the connection as needed.
3. ??

Option two seems the most logical to me. However, I am no CS major nor do I fully understand how all of these technology works.

I thought back to the old myth of, Lightbulbs will use more energy if you turn them on and off frequently. According to my knowledge, this is not the case. I also feel like it is not the case when talking about SSE's and that just letting it run for no reason will waste unnecessary bandwidth.

Any thoughts?

Comment: "efficient" by what measure?

Comment: By comparison of 1 vs 2

Comment: I meant: what are the metrics you're using to evaluate and compare those two choices? Is it latency? Number of simultaneous open connections? Something else?

Comment: it's not a waste/unnecessary if you're using it. and it's not much bandwidth either, maybe 50kb an hour if done right; single images are more...

Answer (score 0):

As you say, the idea behind SSEs is that you need to keep a connection open, then after some time closes it and repeat the process. The problem is that if you keep many connection open, you may ended to eventually exhaust all of them. This is really bad.

If you want implement an "efficient" SSEs with php, you need an **event loop**, such as that provided by platform such as Node.JS or Twisted for Python. We have [React](https://github.com/reactphp/react). And you should use it.

On google I've only found some [old repository](https://github.com/clue/php-sse-react/blob/master/examples/server.php), but they should give you an idea of what to do.

<sup>... or just use Node.js: the right tool for the right job.</sup>

Comment: An event loop will not help to reduce the number of connections nor the bandwidth. It only permits to have multiple connections per process and do async things. So it's more efficient at system level because you'll get less processes, but not all use cases in PHP require such a "complex" setup (eg. processing a task and simply sending back progress).
Also, if I'd go for the event loop, I would not choose React but Amp (https://github.com/amphp/amp) which is far more advanced, better designed and driven by smart people.